# data-layout="box_count" doesent display correct width

Tags: css, facebook

Im struggling with a really strange problem.

When im using data-layout="box_count" on the like button, the width of the liked frame is beeing cut but when I use data-layout="standard" the with is absolutly correct.

The code Im using is HTML5 and is right out the developer box.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=504558953003252&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

This are some images of how it looks for me,

data-layout="box_count"

[image]

data-layout="standard"

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Please file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your CSS and make sure nothing prevents the iframe from being drawn as the plugin wishes.

I had the exact same problem a few days ago and after filing a bug report, Facebook told me which CSS style was conflicting.

Some things you should watch :

- Check if there is a `max-width:`  on the iframe element or its containers (this was my case, I modified a WordPress theme for a client and this was in the CSS reset, so I didn't notice...)
- Try to force `overflow: visible` on all the iframe's parents (documentation suggests so)

From the  [Like Button documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/) :

> **When I click the Like button, the comment popup window ('flyout') doesn't show. Why?**
>
> If the Like button is placed near the edge of an HTML element with the CSS overflow property set to hidden, the flyout may be clipped or completely hidden when the button is clicked. This can be remedied by setting the overflow property to a value other than hidden, such as visible, scroll, or auto.